# Загрузка больших данных в базу Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, excel

Разобрал Excel файл в котором 23000 товаров. Возникает вопрос, как быстро засунуть их базу? И можно ли это сделать на локалке?

Comment: только через консоль/очередь

Comment: сохранить ексель как *.csv. А мускул это ест.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, было решено использовать очереди. Сначала не мог разобраться, потом вкурил. Спарсил Excel и разбил массив на блоки по 200 строк. И каждый блок отправил в очередь. Очереди хранил в базе данных. На сервере можно будет развернуть Redis и работать в многопоточном режиме.

Answer (score 0):

Ранее решал похожую задачу, во время которой нашел несколько вариантов.

1. Самый быстрый способ это импорт, который можно делать и напрямую с Laravel посредством SQL запроса, смотрите в сторону `LOAD DATA`, файлом csv.(Загрузить 200к записей у меня занимало около 2 секунд, при условии типа таблицы MyISAM). Подробнее: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html
2. Отправка пакетом через очереди, тут можно спокойно до 10к записей отправлять на одну очередь, можно даже через модель `Model::insert($array)`. *(Из минусов текущей реализации что данные могут быть вставлены произвольно(зависит какое задание закончит работу раньше), не по порядку, тут зависит от того как вы организовали массив)*